# itunes commercial podcast piracy security

Tags: itunes, security, podcasts, drm

I'm just wondering how secure commercial podcasts on itunes are protected against piracy?

Does it even matter for security if the podcast is provided over itunes or is it the content provider himself who must make the proper security adjustments?

NOTE: Yes I know that all security measures can be bypassed especially in this part of IT. But it makes a difference if it takes 2-3 minutes or 2-3 years ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security must be provided by the content provider, though iTunes can access password-protected podcasts. The content provider sets up password protection via HTTP authorization and/or SSL encryption. It's then as secure as SSL, which is the standard for encryption on the Web, used by Websites for secure transactions, such as stores, credit cards, etc.

See [this link](http://www.potionfactory.com/blog/2006/02/20/password-protecting-podcast) for more on setting it up.

Once you've set it up, you can access the podcast via iTunes by clicking a link on the content provider's site. iTunes gives you an authorization dialog to access the podcast:

[image: iTunes authorization dialog]

Apple [says](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/creatorfaq.html) it does not list password-protected podcasts on the iTunes Store.